How to close task_1 discord.py
i need to close task_1 i try use close(), logout(), and serch to fix my problem i idk
import discord
import asyncio
from asyncio import create_task, run

class MyClient(discord.Client):
    async def on_ready(self):
        print('Logged on as', self.user)

async def main():
    task_1 = create_task(MyClient().start("Token"))
    await asyncio.sleep(30)
    task_2 = create_task(MyClient().start("Token"))

    await task_1
    await task_2

if __name__ == '__main__':
    run(main())

